# Can FFmpeg’s “silenceremove” be used with an MP4 video file?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I've been trying to figure out a way to use FFmpeg's [`silenceremove`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silenceremove) filter on an MP4 file to delete the silent parts just like with MP3s. Has anyone had any luck with doing this with FFmpeg, or any similar tools?

I've tried using [this tool](https://github.com/jordancurve/removesilence) and the resulting MP4 output is buggy/unusable.

Comment: *"delete the silent parts"* -- Are you saying you wish to automatically cut the video (remove sections) when there is no sound?

Comment: Yes, just like silenceremove creates a 'supercut' of an mp3, I want it to work the same for an mp4.

Comment: Yes, this would be fantastic to automatically remove the silence at the beginning of studio recordings.